# Does Qt Builder have a built-in tool for editing a toolbar?

Tags: qt, toolbar, edit, builder

By default, Qt Builder adds a toolbar to a Qt4 GUI Application.

How do I edit the toolbar? I right-clicked it but there was nothing useful in the menu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find the Action Editor, create a new action (either by right-clicking and selecting new, or clicking on the New icon, which looks like a blank page), give the action a name, click ok to close the New Action dialog, and finally drag and drop the action into the toolbar.